# Proportional division of a number (given percentages)

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, arithmetic, divisibility

I have clusters of a given length (minimum length = 3). I would like to distribute the points from each cluster given three percentages (e.g. train = 70%, test = 20%, validation = 10%). I would like to provide each set at least one datapoint and end up with three numbers which resemble as closely as possible the percentages stated.

So, for instance:

cluster length = 3:
train: 1
test: 1
validation:1

cluster length = 7:
train: 4 (floor)
test: 2
validation: 1

cluster length= 10:
train: 7
test: 2
validation: 1

I was wondering if there is a smooth way of doing it.

Comment: Have a look at [partitions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)).

Comment: This is very similar to proportional elections in politics, so you might want to have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proportional_representation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the validation set is the smallest, start by determining the size of that. If you have $n$ points, then
$$|\text{Validation set}| = \max\{1, \text{int}(0.1\cdot n)\}$$
where $\text{int}(x)$ is $x$ rounded to the nearest integer. Next,
$$|\text{Test set}| = \max\{1,\text{int}(0.3\cdot n)\}$$
and finally
$$|\text{Training set}| = n-|\text{Validation set}|-|\text{Test set}|.$$